# Dropdown menu not clicking in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time

url = "https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/nike/shoes/low-top-sneakers/space-hippie-04-recycled-stretch-knit-sneakers/19971654707345242"

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

browser.get(url)

element_dropdown = browser.find_element_by_class_name("CombinedSelect11__field CombinedSelect11__field--selectableOption CombinedSelect11__field--nativeSelect")
select = Select(element_dropdown)

try:
    select.select_by_visible_text("8")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("the item doesnt exist")
```

I am trying to locate the dropdown menu of the link in my code. Once the dropdown box is located I want to search by visible text for a size 8. However whatever I try it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `explicit wait` and then perform your operation. Please take a look at the below code which I have written to replicate your scenario. It's working fine for me. Do let me know if you face any problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://www.mrporter.com/en-gb/mens/product/nike/shoes/low-top-sneakers/space-hippie-04-recycled-stretch-knit-'
    'sneakers/19971654707345242')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Select a size"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@data-value="8"]'))).click()
```